# Compactness of the whole space by compactness of subspaces.

Tags: general-topology

Take double arrow space $[0,1]\times \{1,2\}$

Where topology is dictionary topology defined by linear order as $(a,b)<(c,d)$ iff $a<c$; or ;$a=c \;\&\; b<d$

I want to show that since $[0,1]$ and $\{1,2\}$ are compact sets in linear order topology themselves, then their product is compact (because finite product of compact sets is compact).

**Question:**First of all "because finite product of compact sets is compact" part is confusing me because we need to talk about some common topology.

And to show the above space is compact can we do some kind of trick and how to become sure the above idea is wrong?

Comment: When you speak of cartesian product of topological spaces, it is usually implied a canonical topology on the product. Namely, if $A$ and $B$ are topological spaces, the canonical topology on $A\times B$ is the set $\{  U\times V \colon U \subset A and V \subset B \}$ where the $U$'s and $V$'s are open sets in the respective topologies.

Comment: The topology you've defined on the set $[0,1]\times\{1,2\}$ might or might not be the same topology as the product topology on that set. The theorem that says "the finite product of compact sets [really topologies] is compact" is assuming the product set is given the product topology.

Comment: Ok, I get it now.

Comment: However, if $X$ is your set, and $\tau'$ is your topology, and $\tau$ is the product topology, if you can show that $\tau'\subseteq \tau$ then you can prove directly from the definition of compactness that if $(X,\tau)$ is compact, then $(X,\tau')$ is compact. Essentially, any open cover of $(X,\tau')$ is an open cover of $(X,\tau).$

Comment: Okey but I realy dont understand the open sets in this double arrow space, for example is this space T_2?

Comment: Yes, it's even $T_5$ too, as are all linearly ordered topological spaces.

Comment: omg, yes if it is defined as linear ordered topology !

Comment: @Jale'dejaled: One way to visualize this space is to imagine that each point $x\in[0,1]$ has been split into two points, $x^-$ and $x^+$. Call the resulting space $X$, and define a linear order $\preceq$ on it in the natural way: $x^-\prec x^+$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, and $x^{\pm}\prec y^{\pm}$ whenever $x<y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topology on Double Arrow $X$ is more "subtle" than the product topology on $[0,1]\times \{1,2\}$. The topology is induced by the **order** $<$ that you defined, so e.g. a set like $[ (0,1), (0,2)\rangle$ is open as $(0,1)$ is clearly the minimum of $X$ under $<$ and $(0,1) < (0,2)$, but note there is no point inbetween them so that this basic open set of the order topology reduces to $\{(0,1)\}$. E.g. a basic neighbourhood of $(0,2)$ is an open interval $\langle a,b\rangle$ where $a,b \in X$ with $a < (0,2)$ and $(0,2) < b$. This forces $a=(0,1)$ here and e.g. for $b$ of the form $(c,1) \in X$, with $0< c \le 1$, we get that this interval then becomes the set $\langle 0,c \rangle \times \{1\} \cup [0,c\rangle \times \{2\}$ (check this!), where the first coordinate sets are intervals in the usual order of $[0,1]$, of course. Try to visualise some more intervals with endpoints of the form $(c,2)$ as well.

It turns out that there is no inclusion relation between the product topology and  this order topology, so we cannot say anything about the compactness of $(X,<)$ from the compactness of $[0,1] \times \{1,2\}$ as a product.

It does turn out that the order topology too is compact. It's also separable, but not second countable. The example has the Sorgenfrey line as a subspace, e.g. It's $T_5$ (completely/hereditarily normal and Hausdorff) as any ordered space is. The proof that double arrow is compact is easily found online; also on this site.